# How to backup MySQL Database to a email using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I would like to know the code about backup MySQL db to an email like if I click the button "send to my email" it will pop-up a modal (sb-admin bootstrap) saying, input your email. then it will go directly to that email.

Comment: What have you done so far? show us the code

Comment: Excute mysql query to dump database to a file on server then use the filename and send as attachment to the email

Comment: @Bilal I don't have any because I'm still searching for a proper code as for that.

Comment: Refer my answer.. might help u

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you alredy tried and what is not working

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI can you give a code snippet?

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis I was searching for the best way in some sites. I might find a good one here.

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this first of all you will have to dump the database.

You can use the [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function to execute an external command.

```
exec('mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME > /path/to/output/file.sql');
```

This will dump the Db. then you will have to attach this file to send mail.

you can use `phpmailer` to do this

To use PHPMailer:

- Download the PHPMailer script from here:
  http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- Extract the archive and copy the script's folder to a convenient
  place in your project.
- Include the main script file --
  require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');

Now, sending emails with attachments goes from being insanely difficult to incredibly easy:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'file.sql' );

return $email->Send();
```

Comment: You will have to make necessary changes.. hope you will get
 it done

Comment: Note: dumping large tables, you may need to monitor the file size of the  .sql you're trying to send through e-mail. Most mail servers have a maximum attachment size limit of approx. 10-50Mb / file. You may need an intermediate step where you gzip/tar to overcome that or split generated file into multiple parts and loop-send them.

Comment: @werner good point... Academy you should consider this too while you write the code

Comment: @Werner I will. Thank you!